# DataCloneError only when I click link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history, pushstate

I'm very new to react and am trying to get a handle on JS the best I can to bear with me.

I am creating a recipe app in React. I added `Link` from the `react-router-dom` package. I'm using it three times in the same component--the Navbar component. Two links are working as they should but the third one isn't. When I click on it, I'm getting the following error:

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History':...

The text after this error message shows a function that I have in the `App.js` file.

What's weird is that when I navigate to the url that is attached to the link that's giving me the error through the address bar, it works fine. What I *think* is happening is that the `PushState()` method is trying to push a duplicate object into the `history` object on the `window` global object but I'm not sure how to get around that.

What I'm trying to do is pass a method from the `App.js` file down to another component but I guess the overall question is, "Why am I getting this error?"

## App.js

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
    recipes: [ //an array of objects ]
}

handleAddRecipe = recipe => {. <-- Method to pass as prop
    *Does stuff*
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Navbar
            *other props*
            handleAddRecipe={this.handleAddRecipe}
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
            <Route path="/add-recipe" component={RecipeForm} />
            <Route path="/recipes" component={Recipes} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

## Navbar.js

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
        <Link to="/" exact="true" className="navbar-brand"> <--THIS LINK WORKS
          Recipe Maker
    </Link>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <Link <--------THIS LINK DOES NOT WORK. Clicking this link produces the error mentioned above.
          className="nav-link"
          to={{
            pathname: "/add-recipe",
            state: {
              handleAddRecipe: this.props.handleAddRecipe
            }
          }}
        >
          <li className="nav-item active">
            Create Recipe <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </li>
        </Link>

        <Link <--THIS LINK WORKS
          className="nav-link"
          to={{
            pathname: "/recipes",
            state: {
              recipes: this.props.recipes
            }
          }}
          tabIndex="-1"
        >
          <li className="nav-item">
            View Recipes ({this.props.numOfRecipes})
          </li>
        </Link>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing callback as state props `this.props.handleAddRecipe`?

Comment: Because that function lives in `App.js` and so does the state that it manipulates. I'm wanting to pass it down so that when the form saves a new recipe, it can use that function.